# create an audio element that will allow playback of 2 audio files

Tags: html, audio, html5-audio, embedding

I need to create an audio element that will allow playback of 2 audio files.

1. Your browser does not
   support the audio tag.

   Your browser does not support the
   audio tag.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What is your browser and what is the format of your audio files ?

Comment: My browser is google chrome and audio files are mp3. I needed to code it on pure html. I tried using 2 audio tags but it doesn't work. I'm sorry I don't know how to use this site properly.